# Verifying the checksum of a file in an Inno Setup script?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, checksum

I'm trying to write a simple [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) installer for a patch, and I'd like to check the MD5 or SHA-1 (or even CRC32) checksum of the file to be patched.

It feels like this would be a common thing to check before an installer runs, but I've searched and searched and not found any documentation on such a feature. (The only mention of checksum in the Inno documentation is [`dontverifychecksum`](https://www.kymoto.org/documentation/scriptstudio/index.html?dontverifychecksum.html), which is not what I need.)

I hope that all makes sense. I'm new to Inno Script (this is only my second installer) and I'm trying to ensure it is of a high quality.

Comment: The patch.exe file will not patch the target file if it's different, but it also doesn't give any feedback if there's a problem, so I want to check the target manually.

Answer (score 4):

Aha! I finally found it.

You can use either the [`GetSHA1OfFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getsha1offile) or [`GetMD5OfFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getmd5offile) functions.

Phew!